# simulate paypal payments with sandbox credit cards generator

Tags: paypal, notifications, sandbox, card

When I make a sandbox Paypal payment by using my paypal account, it works fine !... I get the notification of the payment in my sandbox.

And thus, If I have a look in the sandbox payment events, I can read the following request path : POST `/v2/checkout/orders/0KX86606R2956702X/capture.`

When dealing with paypal accounts payments, everything works fine.
The problem I face, is when I try to make a payment without using a paypal account, but by using a virtual Credit Card number by using the paypal credit card generator :

> https://developer.paypal.com/tools/sandbox/card-testing/#link-testcardnumbers.

While I get a successful transaction from my application, I get no trace of the transaction in the sandbox notification panel. And moreover, If I have a look in the sandbox payment events, I can read the following request path :

```
 POST /v2/checkout/orders ...
```

so it seems that the request is different compared to the previous one, when dealing with paypal payments.

So I'm lost and I can't understand what happens with credit cards payments while paypal payments work !
what are the difference between the 2 payment solutions ? Any one has an idea to recover the things ?
Ipoint out that my paypal profile is professional and then make me allow to receive all king of payments in my account. Many thanks to all for your great ideas ! ;-)

I've tried a paypal sandbox payment by using a paypal account : it works !
I've tried to make a payment by directly using a virtual credit card generator given by paypal : Nothing works

I want to understand what are the differences between the 2 payment solutions and why the result of the transaction is not visible in my sandbox notification panel ? How to recover the things ?

Moreover, see the hereafter detailed info :

I would say, it's a quite simple example of SDK integration. hereafter my "pay.php" code :

```
use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Core\PayPalHttpClient;
use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Core\SandboxEnvironment;
use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Orders\OrdersCreateRequest;
require __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";

if (isset($_POST['amount'])) {
$amount = floatval($_POST['amount']);


// Creating an environment
$clientId = PAYPAL_ID;
$clientSecret = PAYPAL_SECRET;

$environment = new SandboxEnvironment($clientId, $clientSecret);
$client = new PayPalHttpClient($environment);

// Construct a request object and set desired parameters
// Here, OrdersCreateRequest() creates a POST request to /v2/checkout/orders

$request = new OrdersCreateRequest();
$request->prefer('return=representation');
$request->body = [
    "intent" => "CAPTURE",
    "purchase_units" => [[
        "reference_id" => "test_ref_id1",
        "amount" => [
            "value" => $amount,
            "currency_code" => "EUR"
        ]
    ]],
    "application_context" => [
        "cancel_url" => "http://localhost/paypal-checkout-sdk/fail.php",
        "return_url" => "http://localhost/paypal-checkout-sdk/success.php"
    ]
];

try {
    // Call API with your client and get a response for your call
    $response = $client->execute($request);

    // If call returns body in response, you can get the deserialized version from the result attribute of the response
    //print_r($response);

    // echo '<pre>';
    // var_dump($response);
    // echo '</pre>';
    // die();

    $ct = 0;
    foreach ($response->result->links as $links) {
        $meinlinks[$ct] = $links -> href;
        $ct++;
    }

    // echo '<pre>';
    // var_dump($meinlinks);
    // echo '</pre>';

    header('location:' . $meinlinks[1]); exit;

} catch (HttpException $ex) {
    echo $ex->statusCode;
    print_r($ex->getMessage());
}
```

}

I don't know if you see something wrong in my code ? but it works fine when dealing with paypal account only. that's why I ask to myself what's the difference when directly dealing with credit cards?... I have a professional paypal account, and therefore I have the full authorisation related to payment means acceptance. Many thanks for all your appreciated ideas !

Comment: Is it a standard or advanced integration? In either case, the /capture endpoint used to complete orders is the same. It is a required step after the payer enters their payment information, and after capture the response is what you use to show success or failure.